# Is there a faster than O(n^2) way to compute a vector of length n from another vector and an n by n matrix?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

$A$ is an array of length  $n$ 
$B$ is an $n\times n$ matrix  \

I want to return an array C of size n such that: 
$$C_{i} =  \sum_{j=1}^{n} \max(0, a_i - b_{ij}) $$

In pseudocode it could  be like below

```
for i = 1 to n:
   C[i] = 0
   for j = 1 to n:
      C[i] += max(0, a[i] - b[i,j])
```

this runs on O(n^2) but it is possible to lower that.

Comment: Your pseudocode has a tiny mismatch with your formula: instead of `a[i]` it has `a[1]`. So it would only check the first element of array. I would edit it myself, but it's illegal to send edits under 6 characters.

Comment: Thanks @user28434 I have just corrected that

Comment: What made you think there could be a faster solution?

Comment: Is there anything you can precompute, or are A and B both fresh and new and arbitrary on each run?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That's not possible.  You have to read in the entire $B$ matrix to determine the correct answer, which fundamentally requires $O(n^2)$ time.

Answer (score 10):

A key observation is that if $i$-problems are completely independent, you need to compute $n$ sums of the form

$$s=\sum_{j=1}^n\max(0,a-b_j).$$

With $a=0$ and all $b_j<0$, we get the even simpler form

$$-s=\sum_{j=1}^nb_j$$ which is a sum of $n$ terms and takes $\Omega(n)$ additions. (If parallelized, this can be lowered to $\Omega(\lg(n))$ using $n$ processors.) In the general case, you need the same amount of comparisons.

---

If you know *a priori* that only few terms are such that $b_j<a$ and you can efficiently determine which ones, then you can avoid accumulating the zeroes.

---

More interesting question is when $b$ is a sparse matrix. Then, two cases: if

- $a\le0$, just add the terms $\max(0, a_i-b_{ij})$ for all $i$. But if
- $a>0$, add $na_i$ and the terms $\max(-a_i,-b_{ij})$ or $-\min(a, b_{ij})$.

Answer (score 1):

While the worst-case complexity is $O(n^2)$, the following special case might be of interest for some applications of this algorithm:

If:

- $B$ does not contain negative values

and:

- $a_i = 0$

Then $C_i = 0$, with no need to consider the matrix entries $b_{i1}$ to $b_{in}$.

This short circuit may make the algorithm behave linear in practice if $A$ is  rather sparse and the condition of $B$ containing no negative numbers holds.

Comment: I already gave more general rules, for the dense and sparse case.